# container or data structure suitable to hold millisecond data

Tags: java, data-structures

What would be a good data structure in Java to hold millisecond price data? 
About 1.000.000 elementsor more in the container.
What is the specific container (vector, array, hash, etc) specifically designed to to hold a lot of data.
I do not intend to filter or sort the data but I do need the ability to assign a key (possibly a tie stamp) to get the corresponding price.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to assign a value (price) to a key (price), you should use a collection implementing the `Map` interface: `TreeMap`, `HashMap`, `Hashtable` or `LinkedHashMap`. You can find an overview of the collections [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html).

If a key can have more than one value, you will need a Multimap, i.e. a map where the value is a collection (see an example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)).

Assuming it is not the case, I'd suggest to use a `TreeMap`, i.e. a map where keys are sorted. Here is an example:

```
    Map<Long, Double> priceHistory = new TreeMap<>();

    ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.now();
    ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.of(2015,9,26),   
        LocalTime.of(11,10,9),
        ZoneId.systemDefault());

    priceHistory.put(zdt1.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 10.5); 
    priceHistory.put(zdt2.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 11.5);
```

It should not be a problem to hold 1 million elements and it should be fast to get the price for a given time stamp.

Comment: You should not use `double` to store price data; floating point is imprecise and cannot represent many values accurately. Additionally it's unlikely you'd want to use a `ZonedDateTime` as a map key because that would fail to match equivalent times in other timezones. Instead use `Instant` if you care about moments in time or `LocalDateTime` if you care about timestamps. ZonedDateTime should rarely be used for anything other than user display.

Comment: I agree for the Double (it's just an example, ideally `BigDecimal` would be best). I did not use ZonedDateTime as keys: I converted it to instant and then extract the milliseconds, as @alfred specified in his question.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't really need millisecond precision, you just need to be able to get *something* for any given millisecond. Guava's [`RangeMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) is great for this, you can construct a `RangeMap<LocalDateTime, Price>` and populate it with a value per second (for instance) with `Range.closedOpen(second, second.plusSeconds(1))` as the key. You can then call `.get()` on an arbitrary `LocalDateTime` and it will return the value associated with the `Range` containing that time. You get arbitrary lookup precision but only use as much storage as you care to.

If you really do want millisecond precision you're going to have a hard time storing anything more than a few days of data efficiently. Instead you should look into storing your data in a database. Databases are designed to efficiently store and query large datasets, far beyond what standard in-memory data structures are designed for.